# How to render whatsapp content in preview dynamically?

Tags: social-networking, meta-tags, meta, whatsapp, prerender

I have an application where i use dynamically rendering of meta tags. I am using pre render services to render meta content dynamically. It works for facebook, google..etc but for whatsapp it is not able capture dynamic content. It is showing like {{meta.content}}.

How can i remove preview from whatapp while sharing from js?

Is there any solution to capture preview dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render dynamic content that you need take help of .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1|Twitterbot|Pinterest|linkedinbot|WhatsApp|Viber|SkypeUriPreview|Google.*snippet [NC,OR]
```

For more info:

https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354

https://www.winhelp.info/create-browser-whitelist-with-htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Prerender you just need to add the whatsapp user agent to the list of user agents being checked. Whatsapp does not support the escaped fragment crawling protocol.

Comment: We are also facing same issue, We added rewrite rule in .htaccess for whatsapp agent, still it shows the tags in whatsapp share, i am not sure, is it redirecting to php which we specified in .htaccess file.

Comment: I commented on your other Stack Overflow question.